# Value Of Matrix Keep Changing Automatically After Each Iteration Of The Loop In C

Tags: c, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, mnist

```
/*Required Libraries*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<conio.h>

/* Include MNIST Dataset */
#include "mnist.h"

/* Definition of Matrix Struct */
typedef struct{
    float** elements;
    int rows;
    int columns;
} Matrix;
float learningRate = 0.001;





/*---------------Matrix Operators--------------*/

/* Returns Random Values Between -0.5 And +0.5 */
float RAND_FLOAT(){
    return ((float) rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) - 0.5 ;
}

/* Creates A row x column struct of type of datatype matrix*/
Matrix* createMatrix(int row, int col) {

    Matrix *matrix = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    matrix->rows = row;
    matrix->columns = col;
    matrix->elements = malloc(row * sizeof(float*));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        matrix->elements[i] = malloc(col * sizeof(float));
    }
    return matrix;

}


/* Transposes The Matrix */
Matrix* transposeMatrix(Matrix* m) {
    Matrix* mat = createMatrix(m->columns, m->rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            mat->elements[j][i] = m->elements[i][j];
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

/* Print the Matrix */
void printMatrix(Matrix* m) {
    printf("Rows: %d Columns: %d\n", m->rows, m->columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            printf("%1.1f ", m->elements[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* Calls The Rand_Float() Function to Fill The Matrix with values from -0.5 to 0.5*/
void fillMatrix(Matrix *m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            m->elements[i][j] = RAND_FLOAT();
        }
    }
}

/* Return The Dot Of The Matricies */
Matrix* dot(Matrix *m1, Matrix *m2) {
    if (m1->columns == m2->rows) {
        Matrix *m = createMatrix(m1->rows, m2->columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < m1->rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m2->columns; j++) {
                float sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < m2->rows; k++) {
                    sum += m1->elements[i][k] * m2->elements[k][j];
                }
                m->elements[i][j] = sum;
            }
        }
        return m;
    } else {
        printf("Dimension mistmatch dot: %dx%d %dx%d\n", m1->rows, m1->columns, m2->rows, m2->columns);
        exit(1);
    }
}

/* Returns a Matrix with Elementwise addition of Matricies*/
Matrix* add(Matrix *m1, Matrix *m2) {
    if (m1->rows == m2->rows && m1->columns == m2->columns) {
        Matrix *m = createMatrix(m1->rows, m1->columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < m1->rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m2->columns; j++) {
                m->elements[i][j] = m1->elements[i][j] + m2->elements[i][j];
            }
        }
        return m;
    } else {
        printf("Dimension mistmatch add: %dx%d %dx%d\n", m1->rows, m1->columns, m2->rows, m2->columns);
        exit(1);
    }
}

/* Returns Index Of The Maximum Element in a Matrix*/
int argMax(Matrix *m){
    /* Expects a column matrix */
    float maxElement = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        if (m->elements[i][0] > maxElement) {
            maxElement = m->elements[i][0];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}

/* Creates A copy of a Matrix */
Matrix* copyMatrix(Matrix* m) {
    Matrix* mat = createMatrix(m->rows, m->columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            mat->elements[i][j] = m->elements[i][j];
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

/* Returns a Matrix With Elementwise Multiplication */
Matrix* multiply(Matrix *m1, Matrix *m2) {
    if (m1->rows == m2->rows && m1->columns == m2->columns) {
        Matrix *m = createMatrix(m1->rows, m1->columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < m1->rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m2->columns; j++) {
                m->elements[i][j] = m1->elements[i][j] * m2->elements[i][j];
            }
        }
        return m;
    } else {
        printf("Dimension mistmatch multiply: %dx%d %dx%d\n", m1->rows, m1->columns, m2->rows, m2->columns);
        exit(1);
    }
}

/* Return Sum Of All The Elements In A Matrix */
float sum(Matrix *m){
    float ans = 0.00;
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            ans += m->elements[i][j];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

/* Returns a Matrix with element-wise difference */
Matrix* subtract(Matrix *m1, Matrix *m2) {
    if (m1->rows == m2->rows && m1->columns == m2->columns) {
        Matrix *m = createMatrix(m1->rows, m1->columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < m1->rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m2->columns; j++) {
                m->elements[i][j] = m1->elements[i][j] - m2->elements[i][j];
            }
        }
        return m;
    } else {
        printf("Dimension mistmatch subtract: %dx%d %dx%d\n", m1->rows, m1->columns, m2->rows, m2->columns);
        exit(1);
    }
}

/* Returns a Matrix Each Element Multiplied by A number */
Matrix* multiplyScalar(float n, Matrix* m) {
    Matrix* mat = copyMatrix(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            mat->elements[i][j] *= n;
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

/* Returns a Matrix Each Element subtracted by A number */
Matrix* subScalar(float n, Matrix* m) {
    Matrix* mat = copyMatrix(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            mat->elements[i][j] -= n;
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

/* Frees Memory Allocated To The Matrix */
void freeMatrix(Matrix* matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix->rows; i++) {
        free(matrix->elements[i]);
    }
    free(matrix->elements);
    free(matrix);
}




/*------------ACTIVATION FUNTIONS--------------- */
/* RELU Activation Function Replaces Matrix Elements With 0 if x < 0 and x if x > 0*/
Matrix* RELU(Matrix *m1){
    Matrix *m = createMatrix(m1->rows, m1->columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < m1->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1->columns; j++) {
            if(m1->elements[i][j] > 0)
                m->elements[i][j] = m1->elements[i][j];
        }
    }
    return m;
}

/* Coverts Numerical Values into Probability Distribution */
Matrix* Softmax(Matrix *m){
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            total += exp(m->elements[i][j]);
        }
    }
    Matrix* mat = createMatrix(m->rows, m->columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < mat->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat->columns; j++) {
            mat->elements[i][j] = exp(m->elements[i][j]) / total;
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

/* Derivative Funtion of RELU Activation Function For Back Propagation*/
Matrix* RELUPrime(Matrix* m) {
    Matrix* result = createMatrix(m->rows, m->columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            if (m->elements[i][j] > 0) {
                result->elements[i][j] = 1;
            } else {
                result->elements[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/*---------------Main --------------*/
void main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    load_mnist();

    /* Create Both Matricies For Train And Test Matrix */

    Matrix* TrainX = createMatrix(784, 600);
    Matrix* TestX = createMatrix(784, 100);

    /*Transpose Train And Test Image Array and put it into a matrix*/

    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 784; j++) {
            TrainX->elements[j][i] = train_image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 784; j++) {
            TestX->elements[j][i] = test_image[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    /* Initialise Weights And Bias Matricies */
    Matrix* W1 = createMatrix(784, 784);
    fillMatrix(W1);

    Matrix* B1 = createMatrix(784, 1);
    fillMatrix(B1);

    Matrix* W2 = createMatrix(10, 784);
    fillMatrix(W2);

    Matrix* B2 = createMatrix(10, 1);
    fillMatrix(B2);

    /* Training */
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){

        /*Feed Forward */
        int label = train_label[i];
        Matrix* X = createMatrix(784,1);
        Matrix* Y = createMatrix(10, 1);
        Y->elements[label][0] = 1; /*One Hot Encoded Actual Label*/

        for(int j = 0; j < 784; j++){ X->elements[j][i] = TrainX->elements[j][i]; } /* Flatten Matrix For Each Entry*/
        
        
        Matrix* dotMat1 = dot(W1,X);
        Matrix* Z1 = add(dotMat1,B1);
        Matrix* A1 = RELU(Z1);

        freeMatrix(dotMat1);

        Matrix* dotMat2 = dot(W2,A1);
        Matrix* Z2 = add(dotMat2,B2); 
        Matrix* A2 = Softmax(Z2);

        freeMatrix(dotMat2);
        freeMatrix(Z2);

        /*Back Propagation */

        Matrix* dZ2 = subtract(A2, Y);
        Matrix* transposeA1 = transposeMatrix(A1);
        Matrix* dW2 =  dot(dZ2,transposeA1);

        freeMatrix(transposeA1);
        freeMatrix(A1);
        freeMatrix(A2);


        Matrix* transposeW2 = transposeMatrix(W2);
        Matrix* ReluPrimeZ1 = RELUPrime(Z1);
        Matrix* dotMat3 = dot(transposeW2,dZ2);
        Matrix* dZ1 = multiply(dotMat3,ReluPrimeZ1);

        Matrix* transposeX = transposeMatrix(X);
        Matrix* dW1 = dot(dZ1,transposeX); 

        freeMatrix(Z1);
        freeMatrix(transposeW2);
        freeMatrix(ReluPrimeZ1);
        freeMatrix(dotMat3);
        freeMatrix(transposeX);

        float dB1 = sum(dZ1)*learningRate;
        float dB2 = sum(dZ2)*learningRate;

        freeMatrix(dZ1);
        freeMatrix(dZ2);

        printMatrix(W2);
        printf("--%d-- \n \n \n ",i);

        /*Update Parameters*/

        Matrix* multiplieddW1 = multiplyScalar(learningRate,dW1);
        Matrix* multiplieddW2 = multiplyScalar(learningRate,dW2);

        free(dW1);
        free(dW2);

        Matrix* newW1 = subtract(W1,multiplieddW1);
        Matrix* newW2 = subtract(W2,multiplieddW2);
        
        freeMatrix(multiplieddW1);
        freeMatrix(multiplieddW2);

        freeMatrix(W1);
        freeMatrix(W2);

        Matrix* W1 = copyMatrix(newW1);
        Matrix* W2 = copyMatrix(newW2);     

        freeMatrix(newW1);
        freeMatrix(newW2);

        Matrix* newB1 = subScalar(dB1,B1);
        Matrix* newB2 = subScalar(dB2,B2);

        freeMatrix(B1);
        freeMatrix(B2);

        Matrix* B1 = newB1;
        Matrix* B2 = newB2;

        freeMatrix(newB1);
        freeMatrix(newB2);

        freeMatrix(X);
        freeMatrix(Y);
    }   
    
}
```

I Have A check for the dot product of the matricies which exits the program if the dimension don't match the requirements
after only one iteration it returns an error that the dimensions mismatched
idk how the values are changing
and on running the program multiple times it is returning random values for rows and columns

this is only happening with the w1 and w2 matrcies

i tried printing out the dimension at the start and end of the loop
at the end of the first loop the dimensions are correct but when the loop returns to the start the dimensions are altered

also tried hard coding the dimensions at the start of the loop

```
W1 -> rows = 784;
W1 -> columns = 784;
```

but that freezes the program

the mnist.h file is

```
Takafumi Hoiruchi. 2018.
https://github.com/takafumihoriuchi/MNIST_for_C
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

// set appropriate path for data
#define TRAIN_IMAGE "./data/train-images.idx3-ubyte"
#define TRAIN_LABEL "./data/train-labels.idx1-ubyte"
#define TEST_IMAGE "./data/t10k-images.idx3-ubyte"
#define TEST_LABEL "./data/t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte"

#define SIZE 784 // 28*28
#define NUM_TRAIN 60000
#define NUM_TEST 10000
#define LEN_INFO_IMAGE 4
#define LEN_INFO_LABEL 2

#define MAX_IMAGESIZE 1280
#define MAX_BRIGHTNESS 255
#define MAX_FILENAME 256
#define MAX_NUM_OF_IMAGES 1

unsigned char image[MAX_NUM_OF_IMAGES][MAX_IMAGESIZE][MAX_IMAGESIZE];
int width[MAX_NUM_OF_IMAGES], height[MAX_NUM_OF_IMAGES];

int info_image[LEN_INFO_IMAGE];
int info_label[LEN_INFO_LABEL];

unsigned char train_image_char[NUM_TRAIN][SIZE];
unsigned char test_image_char[NUM_TEST][SIZE];
unsigned char train_label_char[NUM_TRAIN][1];
unsigned char test_label_char[NUM_TEST][1];

double train_image[NUM_TRAIN][SIZE];
double test_image[NUM_TEST][SIZE];
int  train_label[NUM_TRAIN];
int test_label[NUM_TEST];


void FlipLong(unsigned char * ptr)
{
    register unsigned char val;
    
    // Swap 1st and 4th bytes
    val = *(ptr);
    *(ptr) = *(ptr+3);
    *(ptr+3) = val;
    
    // Swap 2nd and 3rd bytes
    ptr += 1;
    val = *(ptr);
    *(ptr) = *(ptr+1);
    *(ptr+1) = val;
}


void read_mnist_char(char *file_path, int num_data, int len_info, int arr_n, unsigned char data_char[][arr_n], int info_arr[])
{
    int i, j, k, fd;
    unsigned char *ptr;

    if ((fd = open(file_path, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't open image file");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    read(fd, info_arr, len_info * sizeof(int));
    
    // read-in information about size of data
    for (i=0; i<len_info; i++) { 
        ptr = (unsigned char *)(info_arr + i);
        FlipLong(ptr);
        ptr = ptr + sizeof(int);
    }
    
    // read-in mnist numbers (pixels|labels)
    for (i=0; i<num_data; i++) {
        read(fd, data_char[i], arr_n * sizeof(unsigned char));   
    }

    close(fd);
}


void image_char2double(int num_data, unsigned char data_image_char[][SIZE], double data_image[][SIZE])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<num_data; i++)
        for (j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
            data_image[i][j]  = (double)data_image_char[i][j] / 255.0;
}


void label_char2int(int num_data, unsigned char data_label_char[][1], int data_label[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<num_data; i++)
        data_label[i]  = (int)data_label_char[i][0];
}


void load_mnist()
{
    read_mnist_char(TRAIN_IMAGE, NUM_TRAIN, LEN_INFO_IMAGE, SIZE, train_image_char, info_image);
    image_char2double(NUM_TRAIN, train_image_char, train_image);

    read_mnist_char(TEST_IMAGE, NUM_TEST, LEN_INFO_IMAGE, SIZE, test_image_char, info_image);
    image_char2double(NUM_TEST, test_image_char, test_image);
    
    read_mnist_char(TRAIN_LABEL, NUM_TRAIN, LEN_INFO_LABEL, 1, train_label_char, info_label);
    label_char2int(NUM_TRAIN, train_label_char, train_label);
    
    read_mnist_char(TEST_LABEL, NUM_TEST, LEN_INFO_LABEL, 1, test_label_char, info_label);
    label_char2int(NUM_TEST, test_label_char, test_label);
}


void print_mnist_pixel(double data_image[][SIZE], int num_data)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<num_data; i++) {
        printf("image %d/%d\n", i+1, num_data);
        for (j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%1.1f ", data_image[i][j]);
            if ((j+1) % 28 == 0) putchar('\n');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}


void print_mnist_label(int data_label[], int num_data)
{
    int i;
    if (num_data == NUM_TRAIN)
        for (i=0; i<num_data; i++)
            printf("train_label[%d]: %d\n", i, train_label[i]);
    else
        for (i=0; i<num_data; i++)
            printf("test_label[%d]: %d\n", i, test_label[i]);
}


// name: path for saving image (ex: "./images/sample.pgm")
void save_image(int n, char name[])
{
    char file_name[MAX_FILENAME];
    FILE *fp;
    int x, y;

    if (name[0] == '\0') {
        printf("output file name (*.pgm) : ");
        scanf("%s", file_name);
    } else strcpy(file_name, name);

    if ( (fp=fopen(file_name, "wb"))==NULL ) {
        printf("could not open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fputs("P5\n", fp);
    fputs("# Created by Image Processing\n", fp);
    fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n", width[n], height[n]);
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", MAX_BRIGHTNESS);
    for (y=0; y<height[n]; y++)
        for (x=0; x<width[n]; x++)
            fputc(image[n][x][y], fp);
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Image was saved successfully\n");
}


// save mnist image (call for each image)
// store train_image[][] into image[][][]
void save_mnist_pgm(double data_image[][SIZE], int index)
{
    int n = 0; // id for image (set to 0)
    int x, y;

    width[n] = 28;
    height[n] = 28;

    for (y=0; y<height[n]; y++) {
        for (x=0; x<width[n]; x++) {
            image[n][x][y] = data_image[index][y * width[n] + x] * 255.0;
        }
    }

    save_image(n, "");
}
```

Comment: Welcome, please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. It should have library headers and the relevant missing functions.

Comment: Check your array indexes don't go out of range, C doesn't do this for you. The problem is probbaly in some code you didn't show,.

Comment: You replace W1 and W2 with something else in the middle of the loop, so that would be why, I guess?

Comment: What is `"mnist.h"`. Show it.

Comment: i have defined a struct which includes the number of rows and columns so i don't have to keep track of the dimensions

Comment: "https://github.com/takafumihoriuchi/MNIST_for_C" Mnist.h is from this repo

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `W1` and `W2` change value from "end of the loop in main" to "top of the loop in main" is here:

```
    Matrix* W1 = copyMatrix(newW1);
    Matrix* W2 = copyMatrix(newW2);     
    ^^^^^^^
```

In the middle of your loop you define new variables with the same names. These variables goes out of scope at the end of the loop so once you get to the top, `W1` and `W2` refers to the `W1` and `W2` defined before the loop. In other words, `W1` in the top of the loop is another variable than `W1` at the end of the loop.

You would want to do:

```
    W1 = copyMatrix(newW1);
    W2 = copyMatrix(newW2);
```

so that you don't define new variables. (note: Same for B1 and B2)

For fun you could try code like:

```
int x = 42;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    printf("%d\n", x);
    int x = 5;          // Definition of a new x
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

This will print alternating 42 and 5 as `x` in the top is another variable than `x` at the end.

BTW:

I also noticed

```
    free(dW1);
    free(dW2);
```

shouldn't that be `freeMatrix`

Comment: i have fixed that issue but when i run the training loop multiple times it just executes twice and freezes

Comment: @AymanMakroo Then there must be additional bugs. Since you now are using different code, it also requires a new question where you can post the new code and desbribe the problem. If possible you should reduce the code to a minimum before posting.